# Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT' within a function - Multiple Inserts in Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, functions

If this is not the right forum please let me know and move it for me.

I've just got a bunch of inserts like this toward the end of my scalar function:

```
   INSERT INTO [Raptor].[dbo].[UserRole]
           ([RoleId]
           ,[UserId])
     VALUES
           (3
           ,@NewUserID)

    INSERT INTO [Raptor].[dbo].[UserRole]
               ([RoleId]
               ,[UserId])
         VALUES
               (5
               ,@NewUserID)
```

Comment: You should be using a stored procedure, not a function. A function in SQL Server is not like a method in OO languages - it is meant merely to return data to the caller.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In T-SQL, you cannot modify any data in a function. There is no straightforward way around it. There are some obscure hacks, but I would not use them. Use a stored procedure.

The hack, quoting from Erland Sommarskog:

```
CREATE FUNCTION loophole(@i int) RETURNS varchar(20) AS
  BEGIN
     DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX),
             @cmd varchar(4000)
     SELECT @sql = ' UPDATE rsci ' +
                   ' SET b = CASE ' + ltrim(str(@i + 1)) +
                   ' WHEN 1 THEN ''Ett'' WHEN 2 THEN ''Två''' +
                   ' WHEN 3 THEN ''Tre'' WHEN 4 THEN ''Fyra''' +
                   ' WHEN 5 THEN ''Fem'' WHEN 6 THEN ''Sex''' +
                   ' WHEN 7 THEN ''Sju'' WHEN 8 THEN ''Åtta''' +
                   ' WHEN 9 THEN ''Nio'' WHEN 10 THEN ''Tio'' END' +
                   ' WHERE a = ' + ltrim(str(@i + 1))
     SELECT @cmd = 'sqlcmd -S ' + @@servername + ' -d ' + db_name() +
                   ' -Q "' + @sql + '"'
     EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, 'no_output'
     RETURN (SELECT b FROM rsci WHERE a = @i)
  END
```

Comment: well this is for maintenance purposes so what is the hack?  So you're saying I'm better off just to create a main stored proc (lets say it's called CreateUserForMaintenance) and have it call these inserts after I throw some of those insert

Comment: You should be using a stored procedure, not a function. A function in SQL Server is not like a method in OO languages - it is meant merely to return data to the caller.